# Run Scheduled Task with C#

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I've created a simple task. It is launched at the log on of every user. I'd also like to launch it right away after creation -> do what "Run" in **Task Scheduler** GUI does. I know that I can start a new process, and execute action target that way. Can it also be done just using the `TaskService` object? This is sample code:

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService()) {
    // Create a new task definition and assign properties
    TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
    td.RegistrationInfo.Author = "Me";

    td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;

    td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Starts Updater";
    td.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = false;
    td.Settings.Enabled = true;
    td.Settings.ExecutionTimeLimit = TimeSpan.Zero;
    td.Settings.Hidden = false;
    td.Settings.IdleSettings.RestartOnIdle = false;
    td.Settings.IdleSettings.StopOnIdleEnd = false;
    td.Settings.Priority = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.High;
    td.Settings.RunOnlyIfIdle = false;
    td.Settings.RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable = false;
    td.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = false;


    // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
    td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger());

    var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath("path_updater.exe");
    // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(fileName, null, null));

    // Register the task in the root folder
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Updater", td);

}
```

Comment: See following : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37252.c-timer-schedule-a-task.aspx.  Just change the scheduledTime

Comment: @Robert, let me know if the updated answer works for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you would right click a created Task and click Run on TaskScheduler GUI

*You can use `Task.Run()` after the task has been registered like this*

```
.
.
ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Updater", td);
var runCreatedTask = ts.FindTask("Updater").Run(); //Runs the registered task immediately
```

Comment: `RegisterTaskDefinition` returns task it just registered, you dont need to find it again